# how can i insert current timestamp in mysql with millisecond accuracy

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert current timestamp with millisecond accuracy. But able to insert with seconds only. I tried with two queries `insert into time(timestamp) values (now())` and `insert into time(timestamp) values(current_timestamp)`. both the queries storing 000000 in milliseconds precision like

### timestamp

2015-08-15 16:25:48.000000
2015-08-15 16:41:06.000000

what i need is like
timestamp   id
2015-08-15 16:25:48.566789
2015-08-15 16:41:06.111111

anybody please suggest me a function to insert current timestamp with accurate to milli seconds

Comment: Please have a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299149/timestamp-with-a-millisecond-precision-how-to-save-them-in-mysql

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: this did solved my problem