# How to convert a Mysql timestamp to sysdate(6) format(with milliseconds)?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, timestamp

I am new to postgres and I have been working on Mysql for quiet sometimes. I need to migrate content from Mysql table to Postgres table.

My Postgres table is like this:

```
             Column             |            Type             |                                           Modifiers                                            
--------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                             | integer                     | 
 created_at                     | timestamp without time zone | not null default timezone('UTC'::text, now())
 updated_at                     | timestamp without time zone | not null default timezone('UTC'::text, now())
 key_classification             | character varying(2000)     | not null
```

I am inserting created_at and updated_at value from mysql table which is in the form "2014-09-04 23:40:14".

when I insert a row into my postgres table the default timestamp is in the form "2016-01-22 17:44:53.342757" which inclues millisecond in the timestamp.

Now I need to add the millisecond to the mysql timestamp format to match the postgres table format.

Please help to add the millisecond into the timestamp.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you need to read [Timestamp with a millisecond presicion how to save the in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299149/timestamp-with-a-millisecond-precision-how-to-save-them-in-mysql)

Comment: do you need this precision in mysql, or do you just think you need it for the migration? postgresql will happily accept also shorter timestamps, even "2016-01-22" as shorthand for "2016-01-22 00:00:00.000000"

Answer (score 0):

Morning Arunraj
I hope this helps ?

I'm running Mysql/MariaDB

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name           | Value           |
+-------------------------+-----------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.25-73.1     |
| protocol_version        | 10              |
| slave_type_conversions  |                 |
| version                 | 10.0.21-MariaDB |
| version_comment         | MariaDB Server  |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64          |
| version_compile_os      | Linux           |
| version_malloc_library  | system          |
+-------------------------+-----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And I'm referencing [11.3.6 Fractional Seconds in Time Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html)
Which is mysql version 5.7

To run the example

```
As mysql Admin 
mysql -u USERNAME -p

CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';

CREATE DATABASE test;

GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'test'@'localhost';
```

Quit and then login as test

```
mysql -u test -p
```

The password is test

Then

```
CREATE TABLE test.td6(ts6 timestamp(6));

INSERT INTO test.td6 VALUES ('2016-01-22 17:44:53.342757');
```

The inserted value is the timestamp format you wanted to insert into mysql.
[image: Example Results Ref msql 5.7]

All the best