# php microseconds convert to DateTime and back

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have exist microsecond `timestamp = 1484923604957` and I want create DateTime object or just date, for then set in db in table with column `created_at - datetime`. I don't want change type field in DB. Now I convert to date like this

```
        $seconds = $mil / 1000;
    return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $seconds);
```

and in DB have `2017-01-20 14:46:44`

and then when get have date without microseconds

```
created_at = "2016-12-29 14:42:05"
```

I create DateTime

```
        $dateTimeClass = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
    return $dateTimeClass;
```

and in response

```
   $dateTimeClass->getTimestamp()*1000
```

this is last microsecond

How to correct convert to DatTime (or date) with microseconds and back to microseconds?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change db field type for created_at - `DATETIME` to `DATETIME(6)` for microseconds. Without that you won't get exact time in microseconds as it doesn't get stored in database.

Comment: I have type `  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,` what type is it DATETIME(6) and how to change ?

Comment: @shuba.ivan refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299149/timestamp-with-a-millisecond-precision-how-to-save-them-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$dateTime->format('u')` to convert your object to microseconds if it was created with microseconds. Please refer to [the documentation for date](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters).

> Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2). Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds if DateTime was created with microseconds.

Comment: In db `2017-01-20 14:46:44.000000` then `$dateTime->format('u') => result = 000000` but needed like `timestamp = 1484923604957`

Comment: If you want an epoch timestamp then you can use `format('U')`