# How to convert datetime with millisecond precision to milliseconds from Unix epoch in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with a date column that is formatted as a `DATETIME(3)`. I would like to convert it to a `BIGINT(13)` that stores that datetime as the milliseconds from unix epoch.

How can I modify the column definition and convert all of the existing values in the table without losing any of the data?

I know you can convert the datetime to milliseconds using taking into account the timezone:

```
SELECT CAST(
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    CONVERT_TZ('2019-04-22 00:37:47.843', '+00:00', 'SYSTEM')
  ) * 1000 AS INT
);
```

Which returns: `1555893467843`

The table is created as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `usages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `usages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `unix` bigint(13) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

Comment: Why do you want to ditch a perfectly good `DATETIME` for a `BIGINT`?

Comment: I want to query the the table really quickly (2 queries per second) and it is faster to do comparisons on an int then a date.

Comment: That sounds like a failure to index the column. I don't see an index in your table definition; chances are simply adding one would speed things up immensely. 2/second on a properly indexed table shouldn't tax even a wimpy server.

Comment: I didn't include my indexed columns because they weren't relevant to my question. Im just trying to make it faster. I know that it works well as a DATETIME.

Comment: If your question is about speed, the indexes are absolutely relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using MySQL 5.6 or higher? If so, before converting you table I would encourage you to consider simply changing your datetime column definition to `datetime(6)` which will natively support storing milliseconds. More discussion on this here:
[Timestamp with a millisecond precision: How to save them in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299149/timestamp-with-a-millisecond-precision-how-to-save-them-in-mysql/26299379)

**If you still want to alter your table you can do it as follows:**

1) Rename your table:

```
RENAME TABLE `usages` TO `usages_original`;
```

2) Create `usages` as desired:

```
CREATE TABLE `usages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `unix` bigint(13) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

3) Insert your modified data:

```
INSERT INTO `usages`
SELECT `id`, `uuid`,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(`datetime`, '+00:00', 'SYSTEM')) * 1000
FROM `usages_original`
```

4) Optionally remove the renamed table: `DROP usages_original`

*Side note:* I don't think `CAST()` is necessary here but if you really want to cast as an integer, it should be instead be `CAST expr AS UNSIGNED` or you'll get an error.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was looking for a way to do it in place. But this will work.